# Minimum number of numbers needed to uniquely define a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

As title says, what would be the minimum number of real numbers needed to uniquely define any plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

What I mean by that is, if you define a plane with 3 non-colinear points, then that would count as 9 real numbers (3 real numbers per point).

The minimum (I think) I have found so far is 5 real numbers (the angle along x-axis, the angle along y-axis and a point in the plane), but I don't know what math I could use to prove that, I do not know what to search for, what terms to use (there must be some area in mathematics about that stuff, right?) and cannot find a related question to this in here.

What I would like is pointers to resources, names of related area in mathematics, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum number is actually three: $ax+by+cz=d$
defines a plane with *unit* normal $(a,b,c)$ (which can be parametrised by two angles), whereupon $d$ defines how far the origin is from the plane.

Comment: Uh, true. Did not even think of that. How would one go about proving such a statement?

Comment: @JeanClaude Because the three variables can be varied independently and they give different planes, three is the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Actually three numbers suffice, since you can always multiply by a constant.  You can make the length of the normal $=1$, so you only need two other numbers.  Alternatively, as long as one of the four numbers is not zero, you can divide it out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying instead of $ax + by + cz = d$ you just have $x + \frac{b}{a}y + \frac{c}{a}z = \frac{d}{a}$?

Comment: Yes, as long as $a\ne 0$.  Since $a,b,c$ cannot all be zero, any non-zero component can be used as a divisor.